# Unselect all in python plotly dash scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly-dash

in plotly dash it is possible to select lines based on clicking on the legend items. At the beginning they are all preselected. Is it possible to unselect them all at the start of the dashboard?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all preselected because the parameter "visible" of the scatter function is True by default, see here for reference: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter

You can can have them unselected via setting the parameter to False:

```
go.Scatter(
    ...,
    visible=False
)
```